# How to use ember-validations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

The [old client side validations gem](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) I was using is no longer maintained.

I believe the author of the above gem recommends [ember-validations](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations). I have searched and can't find any guides regarding how to use the ember-validations gem with Rails.

Is anyone able to suggest any resources for how to achieve this?

Comment: Is there something you're trying to accomplish, specifically?

Comment: Client side validations on an association in a nested form using select2. I am using jquery-validation in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using ember as part of your Rails app, you can follow these steps for the version from Dockyard. Also, read through their documentation [here](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations):

1. Get the Ember-Validations javascript from Dockyard.

   - In a new directory: git clone git://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations.git
   - cd ember-validations
   - bundle install
   - bundle exec rake dist
2. The build will produce several files in the dist folder. Copy the file "ember-validations.js" to the mixins folder of your ember app.
3. Extend every model in your Ember app that you want to validate. For example, it might look like this:

   ```
   App.User = DS.Model.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {
     name: DS.attr('string'),
     (etc...)
   ```
4. Reopen the each  model and write the validations like the documentation shows. For example:

   ```
   App.User.reopen({
     validations: {
       firstName: {
         presence: true,
         length: { minimum: 5 }
       },
       age: {
         numericality: true
       },
       profile: true
     }
   });
   ```
5. You might need to add something to your create and update actions in your controllers to check that the model is validated before saving. You can chain .validate().then(). For example:

   ```
   App.UsersAddNameController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
     actions: {
       addName: function(present){
         currentRecord = this.store.createRecord('name', {
           name: this.get('newName'),
         });
         currentRecord.validate().then(function(){
           currentRecord.save()
         },
         function(){
           alert(currentRecord.get('errors.name'))
         })
       }
     }
   });
   ```